# Most efficient way to calculate percentage in php

Tags: php

i have a database with the current tax value (it is given in percentages to add like 41, 51 etc lets say it is 41 $tax = 41) The tax comes from the database the price is a post variable.

What i want to do is calcutate the new price when the tax is added.
Currently i have.

```
$price = 120;
$tax = 41;
$total = (($price *100 + $price * $percentage)/100);
```

Is there any way to make it easyer? like:

```
$total = $price * 1.$tax
```

i know the last one wont work but its just what i had in mind.

What is the best solution?

Comment: In general,since SQL is much faster,you should do anything that you need firstly in SQL.

Comment: `total = price * (1 + tax/100)`

Comment: Mihai the price dosnt come from the database ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the percentage when querying database or go for

```
$total = $price * (1 + $tax/100);
```

Comment: that would be less cause $price * (41/100 = 0.41) would give 41 as resuld i need to add the $price at the end and it will work thx ;)

Comment: will accept the answer if time has passed are the 2nd () needed it can be (1 + $tax/100) i guess

Comment: Yes you can omit the 2nd parenthesis.